# SD-EXT file system damaged in a few days

Tags: file-system, sd-ext

I'm running an cooked Android on my HD2 with the sd-ext partition trick to increase storage space.

I noticed that with more than just one ROM that file system gets corrupted in a very short time. In a few days of running the FS gets so corrupted that Android itself can't boot. I have to `fsck` from my Linux machine and get lots of lost files before turning the phone on again (and every time I lose something).

While the obvious answer (I actually haven't asked anything yet) may seem to "try another ROM", my question is: what could be causing this corruption of the file system as soon as I **always** turn off my phone the clean way?

Could it be some program running on top of Android? Unbelievable, Linux kernel handles file system internally. AFAIK, virtually no app can damage a file system if only operating with file read and write

Could it be the Android kernel?

Could it be the specific `data2sd` script that I install from recovery? I don't think so because what it does is to merely install an init script that runs once per boot and mounts the card.

I'm asking if anyone here had the same problem, and if and how he/she managed to fix it.

Comment: I forgot to mention: this happens cyclically. Every time I fix the file system, in a few days the same occurs again

Comment: No "outages" / sudden restarts or the like? I cannot think of anything else which could cause this. Maybe a faulty driver, not sure.

Comment: Although there shouldn't be a difference in theory, as long as you do always shut down your phone cleanly: Are you using a journaled file system, i.e. Ext3 or Ext4? Switching to one might help.

Comment: Another thing: Have you checked that the SD card is properly inserted?

Comment: @Erik interesting point. I insert the SD gently until it locks by itself. I think there is no better way to insert an SD. About outages, I'm currently formatting my ROM and I'll make sure that in case of a sudden reboot I'll check the FS